# how to set data using jquery for an anchor for an anchor element created through jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I already have an anchor tag created from jquery. This anchortag creates another anchor tag using

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.link', function (e){}
```

Now I have to set data for this second anchor tag created. Previously,data was set for first anchor like this

```
$('selector').data('param', data)
```

but same thing is not working for another created anchor, please help me solve this.

Basically on search anchor-a was created.
On clicking anchor-a , anchor-b was created.

For setting data for anchor-a, this method was used

```
$('selector').data('param', data)
```

now, how do we set data form anchor-b as well

Comment: Indentation is required! and it is unclear, Please be more specific with your code

Comment: i edited the question with more information please have a look

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QGsza/97/ its working . alert is popped for both links

Comment: Try to post your code, its hard to imagine what your trying to do with your explaination

Comment: set data for anchor-b after it is created. It can be set the same way as long as the anchor is already on the page. In other words, set anchor-b data inside the anchor a click handler